# GGbiplot some additional color for some datapoints

Tags: r, ggbiplot

Is it possible in `ggbiplot` package in R to mark some special data points like data point with `Alcohol = 13.2` in another color then in the clusters. I want to highlight some specific data points.

```
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
print(ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class, 
   ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be done within the `ggbiplot` call, but it is certainly possible by adding another layer. Here is an example:

```
library(ggbiplot)

data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
p <- ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class, 
               ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE)
```

now subset the points you would like to highlight:

```
wine.pca$x[wine$Alcohol == 13.2, 1:2, drop = FALSE] #drop = FALSE to keep matrix class
```

and provide that as `data` to `geom_point`:

```
p + geom_point(data = wine.pca$x[wine$Alcohol == 13.2, 1:2, drop = FALSE],
              aes(x = PC1, y = PC2), color = "black")
```

[image]

you can also do something like this:

```
p + geom_point(data = wine.pca$x[wine$Alcohol == 13.2, 1:2, drop = FALSE],
               aes(x = PC1, y = PC2), color = "black", shape = 21, size = 7)
```

[image]

however this might be too much if you want to highlight many points:

```
p + geom_point(data = wine.pca$x[wine$Alcohol >= 13.2, 1:2],
               aes(x = PC1, y = PC2), color = "black", shape = 21, size = 7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `ggbiplot` is a valid `ggplot2` object, you can add `geom` on it just as you would with other ggplots.

```
cond <- wine.pca$x[which(wine$Alcohol == 13.2),]
cond[1:2]
```

Returns:

```
       PC1        PC2 
-2.2032498 -0.3324551
```

Here's the code. Notice we use `geom_point` and point to PC1 and PC2 respectively for the x and y axes where `wine$Alcohol==13.2`:

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine) 
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE) + 
geom_point(aes(x=cond[1], y=cond[2]), col="goldenrod2", size=3)
```

[image]